# ViewBinding has a conflict with DataBinding

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-viewbinding

In my project, ViewBinding has a conflict with DataBinding when compiling.
[image]

LayoutListCoverMaskBinding is a subclass of ViewBinding, but the parameter requires a type of DataBinding
[image]

My layout file:
[image]

Both DataBinding and ViewBinding are enable

```
viewBinding {
    enabled = true
}
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
```

Can someone clarify me why this happen and if there is a way to solve it?

Comment: Are you using data binding just to replace FindViewById?

Comment: @SomeshKumar Not data binding but view binding.

Comment: @SomeshKumar Prepare to deprecate data binding and replace it with view binding.

Comment: try to remove <layout> tag from this specific layout and try

Comment: @SomeshKumar I want to create a new viewbinding layout while retaining the old databinding layout, can I?

Comment: Yes, you can. @Charming does the above method resolved the issue?

Answer (score 2):

You must wrap into `<layout></layout>` tags all of your layouts that are included in DataBinding layouts otherwise ViewBinding framework will generate its own binding for it and this is incompatible with the binding used by DataBinding.

So make sure that the root element of your `layout_list_cover_mask.xml` is a `<layout>`

Answer (score 0):

You should do as Guni suggested if you want to maintain then both. But, I will suggest to use only viewBinding  because it is much faster and with it you don't have to wrap any view groups with   and its syntax is simplified. If you want to use two ways binding then you can combine both (viewBinding and dataBinding). Chose only one to avoid troubles.